# Does a singular positive semidefinite matrix always construct a seminorm?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose, we define a quadratic form $Q(x)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} x_1 \\ x_2\end{array} \right)^\top \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{array} \right) \left(\begin{array}{cc} x_1 \\ x_2\end{array} \right)=(x_1+x_2)^2$. Then the above quadratic with respect to positive semidefinite matrix $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{array} \right)$  defines a semi-norm as any non-zero point x along $x_1+x_2=0$ is having $Q(x)=0$. Can we generalize it to any singular positive semi-definite matrix?

Comment: What do you mean "as well"? The example you provided is singular, not positive definite.

Comment: The matrix A is not positive definite but it is positive semidefinite. I have taken singular positively semidefinite matrix intentionally in order to define semi-norm. There was no need to write as well, I deleted it.

Comment: So the question is whether $A$ can be any other positive semi-definite matrix? The answer is yes; it's not hard to prove... just follow the axioms.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I was looking for explicit examples of semi-norm and singular positive semidefinite matrices are great source for such types of examples.

Comment: This is not only a great source of examples, but the *only* examples, as long as you're dealing with (bounded in the infinite dimensional case) quadratic forms.

Comment: Thanks, further we can say that any point from the null space of the positive semi-definite matrix A will $Q(x)=x^\top Ax =0$.